# Would gravitons follow the same trajectory as photons through a gravitational lense?

Tags: particle-physics, astrophysics, gravitational-lensing

Would gravitons follow the same trajectory as photons through a gravitational lense? would all other particles follow the same trajectory?

Answer (score 3):

All massless particles follow the same trajectory, so gravitional and light radiation would follow the same path. Massive particles follow a different trajectory, which is unsurprising as they travel at a different speed to massless particles.

The calculation of the trajectory in a Schwarzschild metric isn't hard but is a bit messy. There's a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics) that describes how to calculate the trajectories, though it will be hard going for the non-nerd.